# Phonegap app not showing in Chrome Inspector

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to debug my PhoneGap app that is running from PhoneGap desktop. I have my Nexus 6p connected and I see some Chome webviews in chrome://inspect/#devices. I have my android manifest set to debugging enabled:

```
<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

And I have the target SDK to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

From what I read here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap I am not missing anything.

Comment: have you activated developer mode in your nexus device?

Comment: Yeah. Like I said, I see other webviews in chrome inspector. Like chrome app and Facebook.

Comment: how did you run the app in your device?